# Frontend Authenticated request Google Cloud Storage

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using a Google Cloud Storage bucket to upload some of my users files. I do not want them to appear as public, so I created a service account representing my frontend app.

I want to know how to make Authenticated Request to Google Cloud Storage, without using the `@google-cloud/storage` npm package from my frontend app.

I know I need to include `Auhtorization: Bearer <token>` in my request headers but, how do I get this token ?

I'm using React on my frontend app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a number of libraries that you can use. Here is one example:

```
var { google } = require('googleapis')
const request = require('request')

// The service account JSON key file to use to create the Access Token
let privatekey = require('/path/service-account.json')

let scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only'

let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    scopes
)

jwtClient.authorize(function(err, _token) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return err
    } else {
        console.log('token obj:', _token)
        console.log('access token:', _token.access_token)

        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + _token.access_token
        }

        // Make requests to Cloud Storage here
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks John, I will give this a try and comeback to edit my comment.

Also, where do you get `scopes` values, and how often should I ask for a new token ?

Comment: in this page https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#storage you can find a full list of every google api service. I believe the access token expires in one hour. for your second question "how often should I ask for a new token", I can see that you are using service account which always have access and doesn't expire unless you revoke its access yourself.

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi - Access Tokens generated from a service account expire after 3,600 seconds by default - which can be changed to a shorter time. Was your comment for this question? I wrote an article that shows the steps to take a service account and create access tokens: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I now succeed to generate a JWT Token for Google APIs.