# Set Bearer Token to get authorization on Google Cloud Storage objects

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, authorization, google-cloud-storage

I am actually using my Server to get the list of my uploaded object on Google Cloud Storage, (mostly images and PDFs.) and I don't want them to be set `public`.

I get the list from `@google-cloud/storage` using `getFiles()`.

I need to display those images on my website on a `<img>` tag.

I also generate a `Bearer Token` to be able to access them, since using url does not work (Anonymous don't have rights to view this file, this is the expected behaviour.).

But How do I use the Bearer token to display the images that I got from the list ? It's kind of confusing. Also, my frontend do not use `@google-cloud/storage` package.

Comment: What list? How is this question different from your other question where the answer shows how to use a Bearer Token?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256106/frontend-authenticated-request-google-cloud-storage

Comment: @JohnHanley I edited my questions to give more precisions. This question is not about generating Bearer Token, but how to use it to display my Images and PDF files in my React Frontend application. My english is very average so I hope it still understandable.

Comment: Do the users have to access to the files/image have a Google Account? Are they authorize on the bucket (role objectviewer at least)?

Comment: They don't need a Google Account to access the file. I use the Google Cloud Storage to store documents for my mobile applications, and I just need to display them, without making them reachable outside my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an API key in the `Authorization: Bearer {Token}` header (as [explained here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth)) from the Frontend will make the API key accessible. Thus, it would be possible to get the API key and access your Cloud Storage files from outside your Frontend. I understand from your comment that you don't want that.

You have the alternative of using [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).

Signed URLs are URLs that only allow specific access (read/write) for a specific file and for a definite amount of time.
You could generate these Signed URLs in the Backend and access the files with them from the Frontend. In the docs you can find a full code sample on [how to generate Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers) with node.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I am doing actually. I find the fact that you have to generate signedUrl for every single file you want the user to access is a very heavy process for this simple task, Am I missing something or is this just how is it supposed to work ?

Comment: After reviewing the documentation, I wasn't able to find any other method that allows users without Google accounts to access Cloud Storage files without actually making the files public

Comment: With requesting `mediaLink` of GCS Object with the Bearer Token, it actually works, but it makes a request for every file you wanna get. for 100 files, 100 request will be fired. Very consuming.

The other way, is to generate signedUrl link as you said, from your backend, at least request are fired on your side and not on the client's one.