# How to get authenticated requests to Google Cloud Storage from NextJS app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-storage, nextjs-image

I'm using a Cloud Storage instance to store images on my NextJS web app.

I refer to the images like so:

```js
... some code
image="https://storage.cloud.google.com/{my-project}/myimage.jpg"
... some more code
```

I get an error as such:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.cloud.google.com{image link to Cloud Storage} 400 (Bad Request)
```

After some reading of docs I found that I have my Firestore settings to non-public so only certain authenticated users can access cloud content.

I can't specify a user since my local developer environment is running on localhost and I don't know how Firebase will see my requests since I'm already logged in with `gcloud auth login` on my local machine.

I have configured and restarted my server with the added `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: ["storage.cloud.google.com"]
    }
}
```

I see there's an answer [Frontend Authenticated request Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256106/frontend-authenticated-request-google-cloud-storage) which explains using a token but I'd like to not have another token to manage.  Is there a solution where I can manage the access using a Service Account?

I'd like to avoid making all the images public with [this solution](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firebase-how-to-access-and-download-files-in-cloud-storage-b8f2cf49aa13).

I do not want to download the image as mentioned in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/download-files).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the bucket could be restricted but if the link with the access token is used, then the image will be accessed.

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{project-id}/o/{image path}?alt=media&token={token}`

This is not the ideal way I want since the token can be viewed on the source code and makes the image bucket accessible virtually publicly.